# Python - if directory contains file beginning with...move file

Tags: python, if-statement, directory, move

I need to create a script in Python which will look to a directory (which contains only one file) and move it if the file is not for the current day. For reference the file has a suffix which relates to the current day (`myfile_030811.xls`)

Does anyone have any ideas for this?

Comment: What do you have so far?  We'll help you, we won't do it for you.

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your answered questions. You do this by clicking the check mark next to the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this? This assumes that a directory called 'archived' is present under the current directory. you might want to tweak it to suit your needs. Also this assumes that all files under your directory have a name of the structure _ddmmyy. format. It won't work otherwise

```
from stat import *
import os
import time
import shutil
import sys

for file in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
  ct = time.localtime()
  datestamp_on_filename = file.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
  current_date_in_ddmmyy = str(ct.tm_mday) + (('0' + str(ct.tm_mon)) if ct.tm_mon < 10 else str(ct.tm_mon)) + str(ct.tm_year)[2:]
  if datestamp_on_filename != current_date_in_ddmmyy:
    print 'moving ' + file
    shutil.move(sys.argv[1] + "/" + file, 'archived')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about bash?

Test it with :

```
for m in `find /some/base/dir -mtime 1`;do echo mv $m /new/directory;done
```

If everything looks good, remove the "echo" command in front of mv.

Comment: well this code will slip into a current python script I have which auto-updates that file. if the file is for the previous day it moves it.